# Microsoft Graph FindMeetingTimes API - Only returning 5 locations?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

For some reason, when i call the above API, only 5 locations are returned, even though I am passing in 9. All the rooms are available at this time..
For example, the locations that don't show up, if I change the request to only try and find meeting times for these rooms, it successfully returns meeting suggestions (i.e they are free.)

I have also tried to use the parameter MaxCandidates in the request but this makes no difference.

My Post:

```
{
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "LiamLaverty@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Liam Laverty"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    }
  ],
  "timeConstraint": {
    "activityDomain": "unrestricted",
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2019-04-01 13:00:00",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2019-04-01 14:00:00",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "locationConstraint": {
    "isRequired": "true",
    "suggestLocation": "false",
    "locations": [
      {
        "displayName": "First Floor Project Room 1 O2.032 Project Room",
        "locationEmailAddress": "firstfloorprojectroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "First Floor Project Room 2 O2.033 Project Room",
        "locationEmailAddress": "firstfloorprojectroom2@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "OG.034 Project Room",
        "locationEmailAddress": "gfprojectroom2@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "GF Project Room 1 - 0G.037",
        "locationEmailAddress": "gfprojectroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "First Floor Lab",
        "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorLab@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "First Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
        "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Ground Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
        "locationEmailAddress": "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "McClay Ground Floor Room 1",
        "locationEmailAddress": "mcclaygroundfloorstudyroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Meeting Room One Medical Library",
        "locationEmailAddress": "medicallibraryroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H",
  "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100",
  "maxCandidates": 99
}
```

The response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
  "emptySuggestionsReason": "",
  "meetingTimeSuggestions": [
    {
      "confidence": 100,
      "order": 1,
      "organizerAvailability": "free",
      "attendeeAvailability": [],
      "locations": [
        {
          "displayName": "Meeting Room One Medical Library",
          "locationEmailAddress": "medicallibraryroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com",
          "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
        },
        {
          "displayName": "McClay Ground Floor Room 1",
          "locationEmailAddress": "mcclaygroundfloorstudyroom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com",
          "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
        },
        {
          "displayName": "Ground Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
          "locationEmailAddress": "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com",
          "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
        },
        {
          "displayName": "First Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
          "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com",
          "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
        },
        {
          "displayName": "First Floor Lab",
          "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorLab@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com",
          "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
        }
      ],
      "meetingTimeSlot": {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2019-04-01T13:00:00.0000000",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2019-04-01T14:00:00.0000000",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The first 4 locations in my request post are being excluded.. Is there a way around this to return all locations? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you run it for only those 4 locations it _didn't_ return?

Comment: @Marc LaFleur - it successfully returns meetings with them - so it seems that it is limited?